# how to upload .webm video in blob url on recordRTC

Tags: php, video, webrtc, recordrtc

I am new to RecordRTC , I am getting url "blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8036/15d7e0dc-5410-41a2-b409-90a138a53ac7" of recorded vidio this i am able to download to clint system as .webm by creating download  href tag.

How can i upload this to server from that blob url. Server side using PHP

Thank in advance for help.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36245495/552182

Relevant demo:

- https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/tree/master/RecordRTC-to-PHP

Comment: thanks Muaz Khan , Now its working good on localhost running on XAMPP but on live web server web cam not starting , i mean its not working on live web server

Comment: sorry it is only not working on google crome browser

Comment: Google chrome requires HTTPs for non-localhost domains. Please install SSL for your domain and it will fix these issues. PS. SSL/HTTPs is required for getUserMedia API; and you can NOT capture video without using getUserMedia API.

Comment: ok thanks , what is maximum video size we can post to server , I am new to this

Comment: 10-minutes video generates about 110 MB of WebM in Chrome 49+, and max-blobSize limit on Chrome is 500MB.Means that you can record about 40 minutes of 720p WebM with audio. Chrome crashes if blobSize overflows the 500MB limit. Firefox's blobSize limit is about 600MB.

Comment: Thanks @ Muaz Khan very usefull info